# Prolog GNU - Having a difficult time with this, lists and recursion

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

So , i still don't completely understand how lists and recursion work in prolog, could be why i am having trouble with this, but i don't even know how to begin this problem.

There is a list of friends.

```
f(a,b).
f(a,c).
f(a,d).
f(b,c).
f(b,e).
f(b,f).
f(c,e).
f(c,g).
f(g,e).
etc..
```

I have to find if someone is a friend through someone else up to two friends of friends.

So example if i did

```
fof(a,e, List).
```

Then i should get

```
List = [a, b, e];
List = [a, c, e];
List = [a, c, g, e]; <-- anything past this point won't work
```

So basically you check yourself, then see if your friends is friends with person2, then see if their friends are friends with person2, if they are then add to a list.

not exactly sure how to execute this though.

Ok, so i got something similar to what i need.

```
fb(X,X,_).
fb(X,Y,List) :- 
    friend(X,Y),
    X \== Y,
    List = [X,Y].
fb(X,Y,List) :-
    friend(X,Z),friend(Z,Y),
    X \== Y, X \== Z, Z \== Y,
    List = [X,Z,Y].
fb(X,Y,List) :-
    friend(X,Z),friend(Z,Q),friend(Q,Y),
    X \== Y,X \== Z, X \== Q, Z \== Q, Z \== Y, Q \== Y,
    List = [X,Z,Q,Y].
```

This seems to work, but it seems i could condense this with recursion, just not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you've defined `friend(X,Y)` to be true if either `f(X,Y)` or `f(Y,X)`.

Your problem can be solved recursively by adding an argument that specifies the maximum path length allowed, and decrementing that before each recursive call.

```
fof(X,X,[X],_).
fof(X,Z,[X|Path],N) :-
    N >= 1,
    friend(X,Y),
    M is N-1,
    fof(Y,Z,Path,M),
    \+ member(X,Path).  % no duplicates
```

To get to a friend of a friend via max. two intermediaries, i.e. in three steps:

```
?- fof(a,e,L,3).
L = [a, b, c, e] ;
L = [a, b, e] ;
L = [a, c, e] ;
L = [a, c, g, e] ;
L = [a, c, b, e] ;
false.

?- fof(a,z,L,3).
false.
```

Comment: Yea sorry, f=friend. I just wrote it out as f to type it faster.

Comment: Thats close to what i need, i think i can get it from here though. I had something close to that, without the N part. Sigh, prolog, either you get it right or you don't. Not my favorite language.